# WPF DataGrid Highlight some rows

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

I have WPF DataGrid. I need custom style for some rows(e.g for rows where 4th cell has negative value). How can I set condition for applying custom style? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a rowstyle with a DataTrigger? You will need a Converter to for checking negativ values.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AmountProperty4thCell, Converter={StaticResource MyNegativCheckConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```